# Fill row with data MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB and I want to fill the row 'userImg' that is in my User model. Below is my code:

User model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

(userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    unique_id: Number,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    ageRange: String,
    phone: String,
    hobby: String,
    fact: String,
    password: String,
    passwordConf: String,
    userImg: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)),
  (User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema));

module.exports = User;
```

Index.js (where I want to fill the userImg row of the User model):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "file/");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

```
router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.file === undefined) return res.send("you must select a file.");
  const imgUrl = `http://localhost:3000/file/${req.file.originalname}`;
  var userId = req.query.id;
  console.log(userId);
  const bla = User.findOne({ unique_id: userId }).populate({ path: "userImg", model: "User" })
  bla.userImg = imgUrl;
  return res.send("Uw afbeelding is succesvol geupload! " + bla.userImg);
});
```

However, when executing this request, the row userImg is not updated in MongoDB:
[image]

In this row I would like to put a URL of the image uploaded by the user.

Comment: Maybe you can try using one of the _update_ methods - for example, `updateOne()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `findOneAndUpdate` method to update the `userImg` property.
Also, your should use `async await` since it returns a Promise.

Try to change your code like this:

```
router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.file === undefined) return res.send("you must select a file.");
    const imgUrl = `http://localhost:3000/file/${req.file.originalname}`;
    var userId = req.query.id;
    const bla = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { unique_id: userId },
        { userImg: imgUrl },
        { new: true }
      );
    return res.send("Uw afbeelding is succesvol geupload! " + bla.userImg);
  });
```